# malicious link added to product description woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Malicious link has started appearing in product description. I tried solving it. Most probably it's some hook created which is inserting that link, but I'm not able to find it.

http://clovve.com/product/laptop-work-bag/

Malicious Link - initheme.com

Need help with some info about which hook is used in generally used to render product description in woocommerce plugin.

## Edit 1

The malicious link appears in this function in wp-includes > post-template.php:

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false) {
$content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );

/**
 * Filter the post content.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $content Content of the current post.
 */
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
// After this step the content is appended with malicious link
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );

echo $content;
}
```

Comment: are you expecting people here to use their telepathic powers to find where it's added for you?

Comment: @IgorYavych: Sorry for not posting a clear question. I'm actually looking for info related to which hook is generally used to render product description.

Comment: ankit please clear your question

Comment: initheme.com inside you content. "panel wc-tab entry-content active".

Comment: @VasimVanzara : yup.

Comment: you can edit description link in side your theme.woocommerce >> templates >> content-product.php

Comment: This file have all content that you see on your page

Comment: @VasimVanzara: I edited the question. Kindly see the update. I'll check your solution also in the mean time.

Comment: okay.I will check your update question

Comment: post-template.php?? not there

Comment: This is core function

Comment: Yes. Some hook / filter being applied on the_content()

Comment: can you share function.php and which theme are you use

Answer (score 0):

The following hooks can be used for that:

- `the_content`
- `woocommerce_short_description`
- `the_excerpt`

So you can probably find your 'culprit` by searching through files for all occurrences of these

Answer (score 0):

First Navigate to single product folder in woo-commerce plugin.find following file.

```
\woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs\description.php
```

**description.php**

content of file is as below:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Description tab
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post;

$heading = esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading', __( 'Product Description', 'woocommerce' ) ) );

?>

<?php if ( $heading ): ?>
  <h2><?php echo $heading; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I'm using Flatsome 2.7.6.

Comment: found something interesting

Answer (score 0):

Updating the theme solved it. Though thats not the proper solution, but worked.

Comment: you are editing your content hook.This link is added in your content if you are move content